# Sonar Gerrit plugin not reporting results

Tags: sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, gerrit-trigger, sonar-gerrit

We utilize the pipeline and after the build completes successfully we are running the following:

```
bat "mvn sonar:sonar -B -s ${buildSettings} -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview -Dsonar.skipDesign=true -Dsonar.report.export.path=sonar-report.json"

sonarToGerrit(severity: 'Major', postScore: true, category: 'Code-Review', newIssuesOnly: true, issuesScore: '0', noIssuesScore: '0', changedLinesOnly: true)
```

The below build log shows that it found a good number of issues but yet the issues to be commented is 0.

[Build log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNvLS.png)

Other posts suggest that it may not be finding the report but I don't believe it's the case as it found a number of issues. Any pipeline configuration advice would be much appreciated.

We are using Sonar Gerrit plugin version 2.2.1, Gerrit Trigger 2.27.3 and Jenkins Enterprise version is 2.60.3.1.

Comment: What is the versions (Gerrit, Jenkins, sonar-gerrit)?

Comment: We are using Sonar Gerrit plugin version 2.2.1, Gerrit Trigger 2.27.3 and Jenkins Enterprise version is 2.60.3.1 and Gerrit-2.10.2

Comment: Are you sure that you have "Major" new issues at the changed lines? Because you're asking for severity=Major, newIssuesOnly=true and changedLinesOnly=true.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I opened the JSON report and found 10+ MAJOR new issues.

I've tried running it with the following parameters just to try to get it to post anything:
"sonarToGerrit(severity: 'INFO', postScore: true, category: 'Code-Review', newIssuesOnly: false, issuesScore: '0', noIssuesScore: '0', changedLinesOnly: false)"

Still it is always coming back saying it found issues but is not commenting on any. The full report is 14mb, wondering if it is too large or if I should be using a different category?

Comment: Is sonargerrit reporting "Issues to be commented" and "Issues in score calculation" still equals to 0?

Comment: Correct, both still stay at 0 regardless of the parameters I use.

On a side note we have a brand new Jenkins/Gerrit environment that I tested this in as well and the issue exists there too.

Comment: :-( Maybe it's a bug, like this one (fixed in 2.1 version): https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43730

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common case regarding to your question is related to the fact that SonarQube checks the whole project, regardless of amount of changes that were done in particular change. When creating a new report, it compares a result with a result that is stored to it's database (with previously found issues that were found in a mode other than preview). Thus sonar marks as new all the issues that it was not aware about before (and if you don't store this information in SonarQube at all - all the issues will be marked as new). But sonar-gerrit plugin can only post issues to the files that were affected by the change it is verifying. So, even if you set to "false" the settings "newIssuesOnly" and "changedLinesOnly", all the issues in files not affected by the change will be ignored.

**Shortly, check that the issues marked with "isNew"="true" in your sonar report were actually changed (for changedLinesOnly=true) or located in the changed files (for changedLinesOnly = false) in the commit you are trying to check.**

Another possible reason is the project configuration settings. If your files are part of a submodule, you'll need to **include the submodule name to project base directories set**. Or you may want to try a feature  **"allow auto match"**  instead. The feature tries to match SonarQube modules to Gerrit names automatically (available since 2.1).

---

Not related to your question advises regarding your pipeline code:

At the moment settings recognition for severity (and other enum values) is case-sensitive. In fact, the plugin ignores your "Major" setting as it cannot recognize it, and replaces it with default "INFO" value.

Another thing, I don't see why do you set your "postScore" to true as you set "issuesScore" = 0 and "noIssuesScore"=0. You can just set postScore=false and skip these settings along with "category" for sake of simplicity.

Also, if you use the version of plugin above 2.0, be aware that API has slightly changed and now uses the next structure:

```
sonarToGerrit (
        reviewConfig: [ 
            issueFilterConfig: [
                severity: 'MAJOR', 
                newIssuesOnly: false, 
                changedLinesOnly: false
                ], 
            noIssuesTitleTemplate: 'Your text here',
            someIssuesTitleTemplate: 'Your text here',
            issueCommentTemplate: 'Your text here'
        ]
    )
```

Though your code should also work (plugin does support previous versions), there is a bigger chance that there may be a bug.

Answer (score -1):

I am also facing the same issue with Sonar-Gerrit jenkins plugin. Downloaded it from Jenkins plugins site.Using Sonar-Gerrit plugin 2.2.1, and analysing sonar scan against jenkins workspace.

For a sample,have changed just one file and provided the project base directory to the path of that file, and ran the sonar analysis in issues mode.

Issues are not loaded in Gerrit with logs

Report has loaded and contains 759 issues
Issues to be commented: 0
Issues to be involved in score calculation: 0
Review has been sent

Comment: This is not an answer to the question and should be a comment instead.

Comment: Sorry, I wasnt able to comment the previous post, hence added here.

Comment: I have posted it as a seperate question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49026039/sonar-gerrit-plugin-not-reporting-issues-in-gerrit. Thanks