# Sonar-Gerrit Plugin Not reporting Issues in Gerrit

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, sonar-gerrit

I am also facing the same issue with Sonar-Gerrit jenkins plugin. Downloaded it from Jenkins plugins site.Using Sonar-Gerrit plugin 2.2.1, and analysing sonar scan against jenkins workspace.

For a sample,have changed just one file and provided the project base directory to the path of that file, and ran the sonar analysis in issues mode.

Issues are not loaded in Gerrit and jenkins logs say

Report has loaded and contains 759 issues Issues to be commented: 0 Issues to be involved in score calculation: 0 Review has been sent

Have already referred the StackOverflow Page [Sonar Gerrit plugin not reporting results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48707380/sonar-gerrit-plugin-not-reporting-results). Kindly advice on this

Comment: Hi Ranjani. You can e-mail developers (me) directly using the e-mail provided on the plugin wiki page. To help you with troubleshooting I need 1) your pipeline code or screenshot of your plugin settings; 2) name of the file with an issue ignored; 3) lines from your sonar-report file regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and for me the resolution was to point the Project Base Directory to my source folder. If you're using sonar to scan all of your source files then pointing the Project Base directory at only one file I don't think it will like that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-49639) in 2.2.1. If you have custom sub-project settings, the filter option "affect changed lines only" is not working correctly and removes all the files from the result. This issue will be fixed in the next release.

For now you can use the plugin without this option (all the issues satisfying severity and is new criteria will be posted to the changed files)

If this does not help, make sure that you have your project settings being set up correctly.

UPD: a new version of plugin with the fix was released